# Add custom attribute to category list in Magento

Tags: magento

Can you add a custom product item to the **category list view by using the category's "Custom layout update"**? (not to product attribute)

Or is this not possible? And if it's not: how IS it possible?

I find it very strange that this isn't a basic functionality, or that there are no extensions dealing with this as it seems to me like this is quite important. You want to give your user the necessary information of a product, but I don't think you want to repeat everything you put in an attribute also in the product title. Seems very redundant.

Comment: please add the reference xml that you tried before you asked this question to the question and we can suggest you based on that

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. By "custom product item" do you mean "product attribute"?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article: [How to add attribute to product list](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/add-attributes-to-product-grid)